# Finding similar rows using JSON and MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL table named `products`.  In that table is a column named `categories`.

The categories column is JSON IDs that correspond to different categories that each product is associated with.

Here's a few examples:

```
[16,49]
[81,112,182]
[]
[22,342]
[38]
```

I'm looking for a query that can be run to find similar products based upon category.

A pseudo query for what I'm trying to do:

```
SELECT FROM products WHERE categories ARE SIMILAR TO CATEGORIES IN id = '1000'
```

I was trying to think if there was a way to count the number of matches and sort based upon the number of matches in each row.  Or something along those lines?

Comment: Can you give an example of your expected output?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`json_contains`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-contains) to match against each element of the JSON array. You have to pass the value as an array.

```
mysql> select * from products where json_contains(categories, '[182]');
+----------------+
| categories     |
+----------------+
| [81, 112, 182] |
+----------------+
```

Foreign keys are not a good use for JSON. They will perform slower, and referential integrity cannot be maintained. Instead, use a traditional join table.